# Exact Target REST API Can't Create Send Definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, send-email

I am trying to create a send definition via the Exact Target API. I've been using POSTMAN to test my API calls. When I submit a create send definition call I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "isError": true,
  "message": "Error creating integrated send definition: JSON Deserialization Exception: Location Unknown"
}
```

Below is the Request I am making via POSTMAN. Note: 'TestClass' is the name and external key of a send classification I created.

```
{
        "EmailDefinition": {
            "Name": "New Product",
            "EmailId": 17,
            "SendClassificationId": "TestClass",
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Type": "Campaign",
                    "Name": "New Product Alert"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: The [createDefinition](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sends/createDefinition.html) method that you refer to is used when you need to create a send definition in Marketing Cloud to send emails from Sales Cloud. Is this what you are trying to achieve? I just want to ensure that you are using the appropriate method before I provide an answer.

Comment: I am new to SalesForce / Exact Target so maybe the createDefintion is the wrong answer. In ExactTarget under subscribers - > lists I have created a list (listId of 90). When I on that list I am given and option to Send which brings me through a wizard where I select an email template (email ID of 17). And I can send that email to subscribers of that list (currently just 1 email address). I am trying to make a call to the API that will essentially do the wizard process for me. I.e. Call Api and tell it to send this email template to this list of subscribers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd like to keep this process in Exact Target only if possible.

Comment: Do you want to make this call from POSTMAN only? or some other application? Or Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the additional information that you provided, as you need send an email directly from Marketing Cloud using the Fuel REST API, the [createDefinition](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sends/createDefinition.html) method that you are using isn't appropriate for what you are trying to acheive.

Instead, you should be using the [messageDefinitionSends](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html) method which will send a pre-defined email to a subscriber that you include in your request payload. Before using this method, you will firstly need to create a Triggered Send. Once you have done this, you can initiate the Triggered Send using the [messageDefinitionSends](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html) method as per the screenshot below.

To create a Triggered Send, select **Triggered Emails** from the **Interactions** menu in the Email app, click Create and configure the Triggered Send. Once you have saved the Triggered Send, you will need to Start the Triggered Send by selecting the Send then click the **Start/Restart** button.

[image: Triggered Send menu]

Then you will need to include External Key for the Triggered Send that you created in the URL for your POST request to the messageDefinitionSends method:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{{insertExternalKeyHere}}/send
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I am looking at the Interactions Menu and do not see Triggered Sends. I see User-Initiated-Emails and Salesforce Send Emails. The User Initiated Email looks to be exactly what I need --- send an email to a list of people. Is there an API call to make a User Initiated Email send occur? If so what information would I need to include in the request. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: User Initiated Email is something different. You need to use Triggered Emails, refer to menu screenshot at http://imgur.com/jVP8Eyd. If this does not appear for you, check that your user account has permission to access this feature from Settings > Administration > Account > Users > Manage Roles > Edit Permissions, then expand the Email tree. Refer to screenshot at http://imgur.com/qUr8iA4. If you still have issues, I'd suggest opening a support case as this feature should be enabled by default.

Comment: Eliot. I know it has been awhile but after talking with SalesForce and some stakeholders it appears that triggered sends are not what we are looking for. Simply put we need to take in a list of emails addresses and send a template we created in exact target to them. I found the following link: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_send_object/ but was unsure if using the SOAP request was the way to go. Any help would be appreciated